# How to simulate locations in real device with xcode 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'd like to know whether it's possible to simulate locations in my app when testing it on a real iPhone connected to xcode(instead of the simulator) ?

It seems that it was possible via the Instruments->Automator in other versions of Xcode but this service has been removed from Xcode 8. Most probably location simulation in a real device is possible via user interface testing, but I've never done it.

I want to programatically simulate multiple locations with a delay so I'm pretty sure just a GPX file won't be enough.

Comment: It’s managed via the scheme: https://blackpixel.com/writing/2016/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode-revisited.html

Comment: @AllenHumphreys this approach only allows for one simulated location, it's not enough for my purposes

Comment: The GPX file allows for a route, of sorts. Just want to be clear that that’s insufficient?

Comment: You can use a GPX file via the debug menu. From memory, the relative time stamps of the points in the GPX are used to playback the route over time when simulating location.

Comment: It could be done with GPX but then the route would be fixed. But ideally I'd like to program the locations is that possible?

Comment: Can you programmatically generate your GPX file(s)?

Comment: Could be done. Now the question is if I can monitor the status of the location through the command line and whether I can import and set up a new GPX through the command line too